# Get decimal number from http.post()

Tags: php, angularjs

I Have on function in my controller,that post values to php,When post decimal values using http.post(),php get it as a round value. How to recieve decimal value into php variable.

**update.js**

```
$scope.updatemyinterest=function(){ 
        $http.post("php/updateMYINTEREST.php",{'INTR1':$scope.intr1,    
                                               'INTR2':$scope.intr2,
                                               'AMNTPERGRAM':$scope.intrstamnt
                                             })     
            console.log($scope.intrstamnt)//2521
            console.log($scope.intr1)//2.5
            console.log($scope.intr2)//2.33
               }
```

**update.php**

```
<?php
include "connectdb.php";
$data=json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$INTR1=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->INTR1);
$INTR2=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->INTR2);
$AMNTPERGRAM=$dbhandle->real_escape_string($data->AMNTPERGRAM);
$query1="UPDATE myinterest SET  INTR1='$INTR1',INTR2='$INTR2',AMNTPERGRAM='$AMNTPERGRAM' ";
$dbhandle->query($query1);
```

Comment: How about your database structure, did you define your `INTR1` column and `INTR2` column as `DECIMAL`

Comment: @ĐàoMinhHạt  INTR1  decimal(2,0),INTR2  decimal(2,0)

Comment: `The column definition follows the format DECIMAL(M, D) where M is the maximum number of digits (the precision) and D is the number of digits to the right of the decimal point (the scale).`

Comment: `DECIMAL(2,0)` will allow `0` digits after the decimal point... Change that to fit your rounding.